# Best way to save data using node.js with Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I'm programming private guild Discord bot and I need some easy and free way to save bot data like warns.
What do you recommend?

Comment: Warns = warnings? I've worked with mongodb (npm library = mongoose) and that's super simple to set up. Firebase isn't too bad, but more complicated than mongo. I don't know much about Heroku.

Comment: Yup, I want bot to save warnings of guild members (but that's not all)

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher Oh man, you're awesome. MongoDB is amazing - it works with no problem. Submit a question with this, so I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, I'd recommend:

1. MongoDB / [Mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose) (npm)

   - Nice, simple tutorial by the Net Ninja: [MongoDB For Beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OPP_1eAENg&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jpvoYriLI0bY8DOgWZfi6u)
   - [Mlab](https://mlab.com/) = nice hosting service (free up to 500MB I think)
2. [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)

I haven't used Heroku in a long time, so I can't recommend that one anymore, but mongoDB is super easy to setup - the Net Ninja has some sweet tutorials that make things nice and simple.